# I've made a Vue.js 3 and Tailwind component and i turn it into a package, but when i use it tailwind don't seem to apply

Tags: vue.js, package, tailwind-css, nuxt3, element-plus

My issue is that i've made a vue.js 3 and tailwind app that have a form component (using some element-plus select component) what i've done is turn this component into an npm package so i can use it in an other project made in nuxt and tailwind.

When i use the component (in the nuxt poroject) first of all the tailwind style don't seem to apply secondly when i inspect the code through the browser some part of the code or not the same as the original for exemple: `class="bg-gray-500"` in the original project but turn into `class="bg-gray-100"`
in the nuxt one

I've tried to import the css file who contain : `"@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;"`  directly in the component rather then the App.vue file

Comment: You should show your setup/code. Otherwise we cannot help you.